# Sequence Generation with Combinations and Permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, permutation-groups

I am trying to generate a set of genetic sequences with conditions. The problem uses a  base 4 numerical notation:

```
nucleotides = ['A','C','G','T']
```

From this, I'd like to generate as many sequences as possible of 10 nucleotides long, e.g.

```
ACGCTATACA
ACGCATCTAA
...
```

On condition that all sequences in the set have at least 5 or more nucleotides in the same character position different. In the previous example, the positions 5,6,7,8,9 (TATAC vs ATCTA) are different giving it a distance of 5 satisfying our criteria.

For sequences of 4 bases, the following set satisfies a distance of at least 3 (No pair of sequences has more than one common same-position nucleotide):

```
    ACGT
    CATG
    GTAC
    TGCA
    GCTA
    TAGC
    ATCG
    CGAT
    TCAG
    GACT
    CTGA
    AGTC
    AAAA
    CCCC
    GGGG
    TTTT
```

The problem relates to the 
[Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KirkmansSchoolgirlProblem.html).

The problem could be solved computationally by generating sequencing one-by-one whilst verifying the condition at every step. I am curious if there is a mathematical approach.

How could I approach generating a set for 10 bases with a distance of at least 5? How can I generalise this to n bases and at least d distance?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this table](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/quaternary-1.html) an $(n,d)=(10,5)$ quaternary code can have at least $1024$ different strings but not more than $2045.$

An example giving the lower bound can likely be described simply using the field with $4$ elements.

The upper bound seems weak. There are $w=1048576$ words. For each one chosen there are $30$ which differ from it in exactly one place and $405$ in exactly two. $\frac{w}{436}=2404.99$  This does not yet account for words at distance $3$ or $4$ from one or more chosen ones.